# `rustc: command not found` in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, rust

Since my project has a dependency on Rust, I wanted to install it. My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Linting') {
            steps {
                echo 'Linting...'
                sh "python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --user"
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building...'
                sh "python3 -m pip install --upgrade build --user"
                sh "python3 -m build"
            }
        }
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                echo 'Publishing...'
                sh "curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y"
                sh "source $HOME/.cargo/env"
                sh 'export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"'
                sh "rustc --version"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, the pipeline yields: `rustc: command not found`.

Is there a special way the Jenkins environment handles environment variables or specifically `$HOME`?

Comment: Can you try putting the `source $HOME/.cargo/env"` and the call to `rustc` on the same line, e.g. `sh "source $HOME/.cargo/env; rustc --version"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jmb mentioned this could be due to the way you execute your sh blocks. Instead, you can use multiline strings in the same sh block.

```
steps {
      echo 'Publishing...'
      sh """
      curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
      source $HOME/.cargo/env
      export PATH=$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH
      rustc --version
      """
  }
```

Or you can wrap your `sh` block with a `withEnv` block.

```
withEnv(["PATH+RUST=$HOME/.cargo/bin"]) {
   sh "rustc --version"
}
```